# Yii2 - Bad Request (#400) Missing required parameters in index.php

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have problem for action view, update, and delete in index.php page, it always show bad request (#400) Missing required parameters: id_kategori and the address always go to ***localhost/training/frontend/web/index.php?r=kategori%2F(view/update/delete)&id=1***, but when i change the address manually to ***localhost/training/frontend/web/index.php?r=kategori%2Fview&id_kategori=1*** it's no problem, also i can create action but then it will redirect page to ***localhost/training/frontend/web/index.php?r=kategori%2Fview&id=1***. Here's the code, its generate from Gii CRUD:

```
    public function actionView($id_kategori)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id_kategori),
        ]);
    }
```

```
    public function actionUpdate($id_kategori)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id_kategori);
        if ($this->request->isPost && $model->load($this->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id_kategori' => $model->id_kategori]);
        }
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

```
    public function actionDelete($id_kategori)
    {
        $this->findModel($id_kategori)->delete();

        return $this->redirect(['index']);
    }
```

Should i rename id_kategori column to id and other id_column just to id?

Version: Yii 2 (2.0.43)

Template: Advanced Template

Comment: You can either rename action parameter or customize the view URL in grid to specify the parameter for action. No need to change db column names if you don't want to.

Answer (score 1):

define **$id_kategori=null** in function

```
 public function actionView($id_kategori=null)
    {
        return $this->render('view', [
            'model' => $id_kategori ? $this->findModel($id_kategori) : null,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do like this

```
public function actionView($id) {
    return $this->render('view', [
                'model' => $this->findModel($id),
    ]);
}
```